# How to apply multiple (more than two) condition in one cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

I have been working in Excel for a long time but only with basics. Right now I am facing a little advanced challenge, that's why I am posting a question here.

I have built a custom invoice for my shop. Outside the invoice print area, I have one column that indicates if the cable is whether extension or modular (this cell has a VLOOKUP formula) and another cell named order type that determines whether the entire invoice is based either on extension or modular or both (mix).

The condition here is simple - From Cell I13 - I23, will show up types of cable, whether modular or extension. If the all the cells have extension mentioned, then order type cell will show extension, if all the cells have modular mentioned, then order type cell will show modular, if both modular and extension is shown on more than one cells range from I13 - I23, then order type will show mix, if nothing is shown in any of the ranged cells, then the order type cell will remain empty.

[image]

I tried If, OR, AND functions. But I think I am making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below approach. I have assumed that all cells may not always be populated and yet you'd like `Modular` and `Extension` to appear if all populated cells have one value.

`=IF(COUNTA(I13:I23)=0,"",IF(COUNTIF(I13:I23,"Modular")=COUNTA(I13:I23),"Modular",IF(COUNTIF(I13:I23,"Extension")=COUNTA(I13:I23),"Extension","Mixed")))`

**Edit:** Above formula will fail if there are formula blanks. If you have Office 365, you can test below formula and see if it helps.

`=IF(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,UNIQUE(I13:I23))="Modular","Modular",IF(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,UNIQUE(I13:I23))="Extension","Extension",IF(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,UNIQUE(I13:I23))="","","Mixed")))`

If you do not have Office 365 then formula provided by @ScottCraner shall work.

**Edit 2:** I am posting a formula which shall work if you don't have Office 365.

`=IF(COUNTIF(I13:I23,"")=11,"",IF(SUMPRODUCT((I13:I23<>"")+0)=SUMPRODUCT((I13:I23="Modular")+0),"Modular",IF(SUMPRODUCT((I13:I23<>"")+0)=SUMPRODUCT((I13:I23="Extension")+0),"Extension","Mixed")))`

Logic is as below:

See first if all cells are blanks (`=IF(COUNTIF(I13:I23,"")=11,""`)

If not then test if all non-blanks (`SUMPRODUCT((I13:I23<>"")+0)`) are `Modular`

If not then test if all non-blanks are `Extension`

If all three conditions fail then give result as `Mixed`.

Comment: There is one problem with COUNTA.  As the OP stated the values in `I13:I23` are returned by a formula which means they are returning a null string and are not trully blank.  COUNTA will count the formula return of `""` as a positive return and the counts will be off.

Comment: Hello. I copied and paste your Formula but it always shows mixed, even with empty ranged cells. Check here - https://imgur.com/S7ex86p

Comment: @Md.ImranHossain Please see edit and another formula solution.

Comment: @ScottCraner I had missed `VLOOKUP` detail completely. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I do not have office 365 and Scott Craner's Formula not working. Thanks.

Comment: @Md.ImranHossain, please see formula posted in Edit 2. You can copy verbatim and test it.

Comment: Oh yes! I have copied and pasted the formula and it works just absolutely fine. Thank you very much. Although, I do not understand a single function or logic used in this statement. :P

Comment: @Md.ImranHossain I have added few comments for your assistance. Try to read about SUMPRODUCT formula, there are vast numbers of resources online. It will then be easier for you to understand what's written.

Comment: Oh that's great. I really like the way you put every reasoning part by part. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCTS in IF:

```
 =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(I13:I23<>""))=SUMPRODUCT(--(I13:I23="Modular")),"Modular",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(I13:I23<>""))=SUMPRODUCT(--(I13:I23="Extension")),"Extension","Mix"))
```

Comment: Hello. I have copied and pasted your formula, but it always shows modular, even with empty cells.  Check here - https://imgur.com/tIictHW